# Semantics and Logical structure in Definitions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, definition, quantifiers

Continuation of [Free and bound variables in "if" statements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820666/free-and-bound-variables-in-if-statements)

**definitions**:

A number is even if it is divisible by $2$.

The number is even if it is divisible  by $2$.

Is the usage of **the** and **a** different in mathematical definitions(sorry for the poor example above, if you have any better example that would be appreciated). Also aren't mathematical definitions assertions ?

A number $n$ is even if it is divisible by $2$.

Every number $n$ is even if it is divisible by $2$.

I know that a definition is **NOT** an assertion and thus cannot be true or false(Right ?). The definition just describes a property(ies) of some mathematical object.

Now for the above two definitons is $n$ a free variable in the first but bound variable in the second ? Also the second definition can be expressed as $\forall n (n\ is\ even\  \leftrightarrow n\ is\ divisible\ by\ 2)$. Doesn't that mean that a definition in a sense is true or false since it can be expressed by a logical symbols ?

Another **definition**:

Suppose $n$ is an integer. Then $n$ is even if it is divisible by $2$.

Where is the location of **Suppose $n$ is an integer**(a precondition) in the logical structure of a definition(after or before the biarrow) ? $\forall n (n\ is\ an\ integer \rightarrow n\ is\ even\  \leftrightarrow n\ is\ divisible\ by\ 2)$ **or** $\forall n (n\ is\ an\ integer \land n\ is\ even\  \leftrightarrow n\ is\ divisible\ by\ 2)$ **or** $\forall n ( n\ is\ even\  \leftrightarrow n\ is\ an\ integer \land n\ is\ divisible\ by\ 2)$

Also when trying to prove "$x$ is even" what exactly should I do ?

Another  **definition**:

Suppose $R$ is a partial order on a set $A$, $B ⊆ A$, and $ b ∈ B$.
Then $ b$ is called an $R$-smallest element of B (or just a smallest element if $R$
is clear from the context) if $∀x ∈ B(bRx)$.

How do I express this definiton in logical symbols(are $A$,$b$,$B$, $R$ free or bound?)?What should I do if I want to prove that $z$ is a $H$ smallest element of $M$ ?

Suppose $f : A → B$ and $C ⊆ A$. The set $f ∩ (C × B)$, which is a relation
from $C$ to $B$, is called the *restriction of f to C*, and is sometimes denoted
$f|C$. In other words,
$f|C = f∩(C × B)$.

What is the location of $f|C$ in the logical structure ?

Also, it would be great to give a list of books that could clarify misconceptions of these type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Some theory*

See George Tourlakis, [Lectures in Logic and Set Theory. Volume 1 : Mathematical Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521168465) (2003), **I.7. Defined Symbols**, page 112-on :

> We start with a theory $\Gamma$, spoken in some basic formal language $L$. As the development of $\Gamma$ proceeds, gradually and continuously we extend $L$ into languages $L_n$, for $n ≥ 0$ (we have set $L_0 = L$). The theory itself is being extended by stages, as a sequence $\Gamma_n$, $n ≥ 0$. [...] At that same stage we also add to $\Gamma_n$ the *defining nonlogical axiom* of the new symbol in question.
>
> Specifically, if $\varphi(x_1, ..., x_n)$ is some formula, we then can introduce a new predicate symbol “$P$” that stands for $\varphi$.
>
> This entails adding $P$ to $L_k$ as a newn-ary predicate symbol, and adding
>
> $P(x_1, ... x_n) ↔ \varphi(x_1, ..., x_n)$
>
> to $\Gamma_k$ as the defining axiom for $P$.

Thus, we can start with the formula $\varphi(n) := \exists y(n = 2 \times y)$ and extend the "basic" language with the new *predicate* $Even(n)$ and the theory with the *defining axiom* :

> > $Even(n) \leftrightarrow \exists y(n = 2 \times y)$.

This is "implicitly" universally quantified, i.e. : $\forall n [Even(n) \leftrightarrow \exists y(n = 2 \times y) ]$.

---

*Comment*

About the natural language, my "feeling" is that :

> *a number $n$ is even if it is divisible by $2$*

is a "correct" form for a *definition*; "a number $n$" must be interpreted as "a number $n$ whatver" i.e. as having $n$ *universally* quantified.

I would prefer to "read" :

> *every number $n$ is even if it is divisible by $2$*

as meaning : "for every number $n$, $n$ is even if it is divisible by $2$", which amount to the same statement.

---

*Question (1) :*

> when trying to prove "$x$ is even" what exactly should I do ?

$Even(n)$ is defined as : $\exists y(n = 2 \times y)$; thus, proving that e.g. $6 = 2 \times 3$, by rule of logic we can derive : $\exists y(6 = 2 \times y)$, which - by definition - is :

> > $Even(6)$.

*Question (2) :*

> suppose $R$ is a partial order on a set $A, B⊆A$, and $b∈B$. Then $b$ is called an $R$-smallest element of $B$ (or just a smallest element if $R$ is clear from the context) if $∀x∈B(bRx)$. How do I express this definiton in logical symbols(are $A,b,B,R$ free or bound?)?

See Tourlakis, cit, page 114 :

> In this case we have to add a new $n$-ary function symbol $f$ into $L_k$ by a definition. That is, we add $f$ to $L_k$ and also add the following formula to $\Gamma_k$ as a new nonlogical axiom:
>
> $y = f(y_1, ... y_n) ↔ \varphi(y, y_1, ... y_n)$
>
> provided we have a proof in $\Gamma_k$ of the formula : $(∃!y) \varphi(y, y_1, ... y_n)$.

In our example, assuming for simplicity that we have already introduced with a definition the symbol $PO(x,y)$ as an abbreviation for "$x$ is a Partial Order on $y$", we can introduce the following symbol $min(x,y,z)$ as an abbreviation for "the smallest element of $z$ for the relation $x$ on $y$" by the definition :

> $\forall R \forall A \forall B \forall b \quad [ b = min(R,A,B) \leftrightarrow (R \subseteq A \times A \land PO(R,A) \land B \subseteq A \land b \in B \land \forall x (x\in B \rightarrow bRx)) ]$

Now, according to this definition, the answer to the question :

> what should I do if I want to prove that $z$ is a $H$-smallest element of $M$ ?

is straightforward. You have to prove that, for $z \in M$ :

> > $\forall x (x\in M \rightarrow zHx)$.

Comment: Great Answer but here is a couple of points I don't understand: 1) $R⊆A×A∧PO(R,A)∧B⊆A∧b∈B→∀x(x∈B→bRx)$ **OR** $(R⊆A×A∧PO(R,A)∧B⊆A∧b∈B)→∀x(x∈B→bRx)$ 2)why $→∀x(x∈B→bRx)$ not $\leftrightarrow ∀x(x∈B→bRx)$. I thought **if** in definitions meant **if and only if**

Comment: @Nameless - you are right for 1) : it is better to group between parentheses all the conjuncts [but note that $(A \land B) \rightarrow C$ is equivalent to : $A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)$]. Regarding 2) : **NO**, the $\leftrightarrow$ of the definition is that between the *definiendum* (i.e.$b=min(R,A,B)$) and the *definiens* (i.e.the "big" sub-formula on the right).

Comment: Ok. Lets say we have this **Definition**: **Every integer is even if it is divisible by 2.** is same as **If n is an integer then n is even if it is divisible by 2**. means $\forall n (Even(n)\leftrightarrow $ (**n is integer** $\land \exists k(n=2k)))$ (right ?) is it the same as $\forall n (Even(n)\leftrightarrow $ (**n is integer** $\rightarrow \exists k(n=2k)))$ ??

Comment: Also why $→∀x(x∈B→bRx) $ and not $\land ∀x(x∈B→bRx)$. Just to clarify it: you put the **precondition** before the $\rightarrow$ because these are always given, because without them the definition will not apply to the object we want. And the thing we want to prove after the $\rightarrow$. In this case this  ∀n(Even(n)↔  (**n is integer** →∃k(n=2k))) is right while the other one wrong(is this correct ?).  Right ?

Comment: 1) Why did you change ∀x(x∈B→bRx) to ∀x(x∈B∧bRx). The first one is right when we have a universal quantifier ?

Comment: So if have to prove **that z  is a H -smallest element of M ?** what should I do now ?? Should I prove $R⊆A×A∧PO(R,A)∧B⊆A∧b∈B∧∀x(x∈B∧bRx)$ **or** $∀x(x∈M∧zHx)$. The thing that is annoying me is that if we don't have  $R⊆A×A∧PO(R,A)∧B⊆A∧b∈B$ as given(aka suppose) then the definition doesn't even make sense(right? we need **preconditions** as they specify the type of structure the definition applies to) so when  proving  **$b$  is an $R$ -smallest element of $B$** it doesn't make sense to prove $R⊆A×A∧PO(R,A)∧B⊆A∧b∈B$ as they **should be given**.

Comment: But if the logical structure of the definition $[b=min(R,A,B)↔(R⊆A×A∧PO(R,A)∧B⊆A∧b∈B∧∀x(x∈B∧bRx))]$ means we have to prove (R⊆A×A∧PO(R,A)∧B⊆A∧b∈B) is true **but** aren't these given(as without them the definition doesn't make sense). So in this sense $(R⊆A×A∧PO(R,A)∧B⊆A∧b∈B)→∀x(x∈B→bRx))$  makes better sense since if we want to prove the truth of  $(R⊆A×A∧PO(R,A)∧B⊆A∧b∈B)→∀x(x∈B→bRx))$ we assume $(R⊆A×A∧PO(R,A)∧B⊆A∧b∈B)$ as given. Do you get my confusion here ? Just so you know I take the definition as a biconditional assertion that is **always true**.

Comment: YES. If $R$ is not a relation or $B$ is not a subset of $A$ or ... it makes no sense to ask if $b \in B$ is an $R$-smallest element of $B$. Thus, applying the def, if $R$ is not a relation on $A$, we have that the long RHS will be false and so, by property of equivalence, will be false also $b=min(R,A,B)$ and we can agree that in this case it is **not** true to say that $b$ is the $R$-smallest element of $B$.

Comment: Also I think the $∀x(x∈B→bRx)$ should be used with the assertion that $B\ne ∅$ on the RHS as using $∀x(x∈B \land bRx)$ is always false($\forall x(x>0)$) since (for example) potato(or any random real number) is not in $B$.

Comment: **STOP** I've restored the original version, because the condition $b \in B$ is enough for $B \ne \emptyset$.

Comment: Yeah...hahahaha. I didn't notice that $b\in B$ makes $B\ne ∅$ . So just to make sure I get this "idea" perfectly: if I want to prove that  **  $b$  is an $R  $-smallest element of $B$** I have to "technically" prove $(R⊆A×A∧PO(R,A)∧B⊆A∧b∈B∧∀x(x∈B→bRx))$ but this part $(R⊆A×A∧PO(R,A)∧B⊆A∧b∈B)$ is **always** given to me in the "Suppose" part of the question because if I don't have this $(R⊆A×A∧PO(R,A)∧B⊆A∧b∈B)$ than the question is meaningless as the LHS will be automatically false. Did I get it right ?

Comment: @Nameless - YES.

Comment: THANK YOU A MILLION(I finally understand it)... I deeply appreciate your help.